# Creare a Link with tag and category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have a list of product that have the same tags, but different categories.

For example: the tag "Spain" has two categories.  So my list is:

```
Category 1 --- 3 products
Category 2 --- 1 product
```

When I click in `Category 1` I want to display it to an other page showing something like this:

```
Category 1
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
```

How I create this link to pass the category and the current tag?

Any idea?

Comment: Ok it's more clear now… You should update your question adding that you want to display products as a list instead as a grid… This link is not exactly what you want, but it the code is relevant: [Display WooCommerce Categories, Subcategories, and Products in Separate Lists](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479)

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec but I think that is not the solution of my problem.. I am trying to use get_term_link() function. When I click in 'Category 1 --- 3 products' I want to show a list of product of this category and that they have a tag "spain" so I try to pass the parameter tag in get_term_link(), but i have no idea

Comment: Duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627032/wordpress-url-for-showing-post-by-both-category-and-tag