# WordPress URL for showing post by both category and tag

Tags: php, wordpress, url, tags, categories

How can I show all posts with a specific category *foo* and a specific tag *bar* by using URL?

```
Example: site.com/category/foo/tag/bar
```

or

```
Example: site.com/posts?category={category-id}&tag={tag-id}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a default feature for this or not but I have an idea as how to achieve it.

> You can create a custom template for this and in that template get the
>   query string by [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) and then use WP_Query
>   [`cat`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) and [`tag`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) argument to fetch your posts belonging to
>   that cat/tag.

Here is a sample working code:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('category');
$tag_id = get_query_var('tag');
$args = [
    //...
    //...
    'post_type' => 'post', //<-- Replace it with your custom post_type
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag_id' => $tag_id, //replace tag_id with tag if you are passing tag slug
    'cat ' => $cat_id //replace cat with category_name if your are passing category slug
    //...
    //...
];

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if (!empty($query->posts))
{
    //print_r($query->posts);
    foreach ($query->posts as $post)
    {
        //Your filtered post
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: just for clarification, since its a bit weird in wp (current version is 5.7.1): `get_query_var('cat')` returns category_id, `get_query_var('category_name')` returns category_name. `get_query_var('tag')` returns tag_name, `get_query_var('tag_id')` returns tag _id. `get_query_var('category')` returns nothing.

Comment: @honk31: my answer was based on the user question, in his URL there is a query param with name "category" so I have used that. If in your case it is say abc then u have to use `get_query_var('abc')`

Comment: @Ranuak Gupta true that. i am referencing to the build in query vars of wp here.

Comment: @honk31: Yes, you are correct, that's how it is. category is not a reserved word for URI. Hence if you do not have that in your slug you won't get anything.

Comment: ah, now i get it, too. haha. you were referencing OP. i was just having the issue of bringing 2 query vars together and was using build in query parameters. and by doing that, i realized the weird wordpress naming and wanted to list them here. since your answer helped me and i just wanted to add these infos to it :)

Answer (score 3):

The structure looks like this, but depending on your permalink structure.

`/category/category-name/?tag=tag-name`

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: This solution work if you choosed to change permalinks to something different than "simple" `example.com/%postname%`
You should also maintain the English localization or you should also change "category" in the url (ex in Italian is: `example.com//**categoria**/_category-slug_/?tag=_tag-slug-1_,_tag-slug-2_`)

Comment: Since the OP shows a couple examples, I imagine their exact URL structure is flexible, they're just looking for _some_ URL that filters by category and tag at the same time, as I was. If so, the URL given their example would be `site.com/category/foo?tag=bar`. This will be slightly more efficient than the accepted answer since it doesn't query the database multiple times.